# Problems with converting files to binary c++ studio 2012

Tags: c++, binary, jpeg

I'm writing a simple program that transforms a file from its original type into a binary form.

However, I'm having the following problem. The code compiles correctly but when i run it, the console window opens and never closes until i close it myself. Also, i have noticed that the longer the console window stays open, the larger the size of my newly created binary file will be. Below is my code:

```
#include <fstream>//to open a file

using namespace std;
int main(void){
   ifstream in("in.JPG");
   ofstream out("out.bin", ios::binary);
   double d;

   while(!in.eof()) {
      out.write((char*)&d, sizeof d);
   }
   out.close();
   in.close();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Accept us2012's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never read anything from `in`, therefore it has no chance of ever hitting `eof`.

Also, using `eof` in loop conditions is likely to lead to incorrect results, as explained in the following SO question: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

(Generally, it's unclear what you're trying to do. `.jpg` is a 'binary' format, there is no sensible notion of 'converting a `.jpg` file to binary'.)

Comment: Files are also a multiple of bytes, not a multiple of `double`s.

Comment: @Drew Well, there are text files that are lists of floating point numbers in readable ASCII format - you could read those as `double`s and then save their binary representations if you wanted...

Comment: The size of a jpg file should not be assumed to be a multiple of `sizeof double`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!